# Showing that $\lfloor\frac{x-1}3\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{x}3+\frac23\rfloor-1$ and $\lfloor\frac{x+1}3\rfloor=\lfloor\frac{x}3+\frac13\rfloor$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have 2 questions about the floor functions:

1) $\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}{3}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right\rfloor -1$

2) $\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{3}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right\rfloor$

As we know that the definitions and properties of floor functions are:

1) $\lfloor x\rfloor =m$ if $m\leq x<m+1$ and

2) $\lfloor m+x\rfloor =\lfloor x\rfloor +m$ if $m$ is an integer.

Questions:

1) Why the first floor function above has to +1 inside the floor brackets and -1 outside the floor brackets: 
  $\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}{3}\right\rfloor$
= $\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}{3}+1\right\rfloor -1$
= $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right\rfloor -1$

2)Why the second floor function above doesn't need to add or minus 1 inside or outside the floor brackets: 
  $\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{3}\right\rfloor$
= $\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right\rfloor$

Does anyone here know the reason? Thank you.

Comment: If I understand what you’re asking, then you know why those equations hold, but you’re asking what the conventions are for the expression to be “simplified”. I don’t know if there’s a standard widely accepted convention for what it means for a floor function to be in “simplified” form, but I doubt there is. Is this from a class you’re taking or book you’re reading, and if so, is a definition of “simplified” given (i.e. their convention)?

Comment: Why did you post your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3349455/409) again? Re-posting is not the appropriate way to bring attention to a question. Rather, you should edit the previous question with additional remarks about what you are seeking. (Trivial edits simply to "bump" the question to the top of the queue are discouraged. Try to make the edit meaningful.)

Comment: Thank you so much. It is to show that $\left\lfloor \frac{x-1}{3}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right\rfloor -1$ and $\left\lfloor \frac{x+1}{3}\right\rfloor =\left\lfloor \frac{x}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\right\rfloor$. I failed to get the answers.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I still try my best to learn how to use this Stack Exchange well.

Comment: @Kuan: Since the previous question has an answer, you should delete this version.